# Ubuntu Bash on Windows - Accessing Windows drive

Tags: command-line, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu Bash on Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on my Windows machine. This is the developer mode through the Anniversary Update.

I would like to access files from my Windows Desktop (or any other subfolder) by Ubuntu command line (accessing Windows drive).

If you can, please point me to the correct reference or guide.

I want to move run code on Ubuntu command-line that will use files in the Windows memory (Dropbox Folder)

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by installing Ubuntu on Windows? What are you trying to access from where?

Comment: @Pilot6 It's the Linux Subsystem for Windows, which is effectively a 14.04  shell.

Comment: @PatrickNegus That question answers both - see the vice versa

Comment: @MartinThornton Ok, sure.

Answer (score 9):

While in the Ubuntu Bash, your C drive is located in `/mnt/c`.

So, for example, your desktop would be at:

`/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Desktop`

Comment: @ErikaElizabeth Please mark it is correct if it helped your issue. Thanks.